# In Perl, what is the sane way for converting a string into a list of its characters?

Tags: perl, string, split

I have been wondering if there's a nicer, but concise way for splitting a string into its characters

```
@characters = split //, $string
```

is not that hard to read, but somehow the use of a regular expression looks like overkill to me.

I have come up with this:

```
@characters = map { substr $string, $_, 1 } 0 .. length($string) - 1
```

but I find it uglier and less readable. What is your preferred way of splitting that string into its characters?

Comment: Tangent: If you find yourself wanting to split a string into an array of characters you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Michael Carman Agreed. For additional humor, see http://ginini.com/perlsaq.html ;-) @hillu Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Sinan Ünür: I found similar code in a short routine that built different representations (hexdumps and others) from the contents of strings. I would agree that one would be "doing something wrong" only if the amount of data grew beyond some boundary and/or if that resulting array was carried around for a long run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would using a regular expression be "overkill"? Many worry that regexes in Perl are overkill because they think that running them involves a highly complex and slow regex algorithm. That's not always true: the implementation is highly optimized and many simple cases are treated specially: what looks like a regex may actually perform as well as a simple substring search. I wouldn't be surprised at all if this type of `split` is optimized as well. `split` *is* faster than your `map` in some tests I ran. `unpack` appears to be slightly faster than `split`.

I recommend `split` because it is the "idiomatic" way. You'll find it in perldoc, in many books, and any good Perl programmer should know it (if you are not sure your audience will understand it, you can always add a comment to the code like someone suggested.)

OTOH, if regexes are "overkill" only because the syntax is ugly, then it's too subjective for me to say anything. ;-)

Comment: Great answer.

On overkill: I did not consider the run time at all. Regular expressions are integrated great into Perl, but when reading and trying to understand code, they often still require shifting one's mind. Which isn't much of a problem with that "idiomatic" expression using `split` and the empty match.

Answer (score 9):

## Various examples, and speed comparisons.

I thought it might be a good idea to see how fast some of the ways are to split a string on every character.

I ran the test against several versions of Perl that I happen to have on my computer.

#### test.pl

```
use 5.010;
use Benchmark qw(:all) ;
my %bench = (
   'split' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = split //, $string;
     \@chars;
   },
   'split-string' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = split '', $string;
     \@chars;
   },
   'split-capture' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = split /(.)/, $string;
     \@chars;
   },
   'unpack' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = unpack( '(a)*', $string );
     \@chars;
   },
   'match' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = $string =~ /./gs;
     \@chars;
   },
   'match-capture' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = $string =~ /(.)/gs;
     \@chars;
   },
   'map-substr' => sub{
     state $string = 'x' x 1000;
     my @chars = map { substr $string, $_, 1 } 0 .. length($string) - 1;
     \@chars;
   },
);
# set the initial state of $string
$_->() for values %bench;
cmpthese( -10, \%bench );
```

```
for perl in /usr/bin/perl /opt/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl /opt/perl-5.11.2/bin/perl;
do
  $perl -v | perl -nlE'if( /(v5\.\d+\.\d+)/ ){
    say "## Perl $1";
    say "<pre>";
    last;
  }';
  $perl test.pl;
  echo -e '</pre>\n';
done
```

### Perl v5.10.0

```
               Rate split-capture match-capture map-substr match unpack split split-string
split-capture 296/s            --          -20%       -20%  -23%   -58%  -63%         -63%
match-capture 368/s           24%            --        -0%   -4%   -48%  -54%         -54%
map-substr    370/s           25%            0%         --   -3%   -48%  -53%         -54%
match         382/s           29%            4%         3%    --   -46%  -52%         -52%
unpack        709/s          140%           93%        92%   86%     --  -11%         -11%
split         793/s          168%          115%       114%  107%    12%    --          -0%
split-string  795/s          169%          116%       115%  108%    12%    0%           --
```

### Perl v5.10.1

```
               Rate split-capture map-substr match-capture match unpack split split-string
split-capture 301/s            --       -31%          -41%  -47%   -60%  -65%         -66%
map-substr    435/s           45%         --          -14%  -23%   -42%  -50%         -50%
match-capture 506/s           68%        16%            --  -10%   -32%  -42%         -42%
match         565/s           88%        30%           12%    --   -24%  -35%         -35%
unpack        743/s          147%        71%           47%   32%     --  -15%         -15%
split         869/s          189%       100%           72%   54%    17%    --          -1%
split-string  875/s          191%       101%           73%   55%    18%    1%           --
```

### Perl v5.11.2

```
               Rate split-capture match-capture match map-substr unpack split-string split
split-capture 300/s            --          -28%  -32%       -38%   -59%         -63%  -63%
match-capture 420/s           40%            --   -5%       -13%   -42%         -48%  -49%
match         441/s           47%            5%    --        -9%   -39%         -46%  -46%
map-substr    482/s           60%           15%    9%         --   -34%         -41%  -41%
unpack        727/s          142%           73%   65%        51%     --         -10%  -11%
split-string  811/s          170%           93%   84%        68%    12%           --   -1%
split         816/s          171%           94%   85%        69%    12%           1%    --
```

As you can see *split* is the quickest, owing to the fact that this is a special case in the code for `split`.

*split-capture* is the slowest, probably because it has to set `$1`, along with several other match variables.

So I would recommend going with plain old `split //, ...`, or the roughly equivalent `split '', ...`.

Comment: +1 good comparision. I'm surprised that `unpack '(a)*'` isn't faster.  It would be good to see this with unicode strings as well.

Answer (score 6):

For less readable and more concise (and still with regex overkill):

```
@characters = $string =~ /./g;
```

(I learned this idiom from playing code-golf.)

Comment: Uh. This is disgusting in an exciting way. +1 :-)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't get much clearer than using the `split` function to *split* a string. I suppose you could argue that the null pattern is unintuitive; though I find it clear enough. If you want a "clean" alternative wrap it in a sub:

```
my @characters = chars($string);
sub chars { split //, $_[0] }
```

Comment: You can if you think it's clearer but for such a small and simple function I generally don't bother. Note that the function doesn't change the value of `$_[0]`. If I were modifying the value I'd make a copy to avoid unexpected side effects for the caller.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. The standard way to do it is `split //, $string`. To make code more readable you can create a simple function:

```
sub get_characters {
    my ($string) = @_;
    return ( split //, $string );
}

@characters = get_characters($string);
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) technique.  It is well-known, and it is documented.

Yet another way...

```
@characters = $string =~ /./gs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` with a null pattern to break up the string into individual characters:

```
@characters = split //, $string;
```

If you just want the char codes, use unpack:

```
@values = unpack("C*", $string);
```

You may need to include `use utf8` for unpack to work properly. And you can also use `unpack` + `chr` to split the string into individual characters, just TMTOWTDI:

```
@characters = map chr, unpack("C*", $string);
```

Comment: If your motto is "of every possible way to do it, pick the most unreadable one" this is a nice candidate.  I'm not so bad at picking up new idiom, but pack/unpack somehow escape my grip.

Comment: Question is, is this faster than a split?

Comment: `@characters = unpack '(a)*', $string;`

seems to work, too. Let's see what else we can dig up. :-)

Comment: I wasn't really looking for golfed / unreadable ways to do it, but almost all the answers seem to be headed in that general direction, so what the heck..

Comment: pack and unpack may be a little cryptic, but they are very fast.  For something pack or unpack can do directly, usually the only faster way to do it is in C.